# php include file with / in name?

Tags: php, include

can anyone tell me if it's possible to include a file that includes a / in the filename? Does the name need to be escaped a certain way when calling it in include? Or not possible. ie. my.file/name.inc.php

Comment: @Satya, Escape what?  There's nothing to escape there...

Comment: @Satya, Not in PHP you don't...

Comment: @Satya I don't think file can have `/` as a name

Comment: @Satya, are you getting confused with the backslash?

Answer (score 1):

A filename can't contain directory separator in it's name on any platform so everything will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible.  Just include the file.

```
require_once('path/to/your/file.php');
```